# DataFactory Web API pass scheduled start time

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory V2 and trying to pass the scheduled start and end time (from a timer trigger) to a API call. Is this not possible or am I missing a trick?

Thanks

One route that I pursued.

[image]

And another through setting the trigger scheduled start as an input parameter. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it out, I was trying to set the trigger value as the default for the pipeline variables. When you set up pipeline variables, they become available to the trigger, and then in the second page of your trigger configuration, you set the pipeline parameters to the trigger values.

Since the fields are truncated in the image, the properties are:

- @trigger().outputs.windowStartTime
- @trigger().outputs.windowEndTime

[image]